# Couldn't find the correct XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am currently finding the XPATH for the input area on twitter so that i could write smth on it using bot but i keep getting the wrong XPATH.However,i've seen the code from other ppl and they manage to get the correct XPATH eventhough we are getting from the same html element.

The XPATH I get is

```
//*[@id="reactroot"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div2/div1/div/div/div/div2/div1/div/div/div/div/div/div2/div/div/div/div/label/div1/div/div/div/div/div/div2/div
```

[Element chosen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wexO8.png)

The correct `XPATH` they get is `//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Tweet text')]` and when I check the location of it in inspect , it appears to be the same element

[other's XPATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe0bg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, try to avoid very long CSS or very long XPath expressions. They are hard to read, not reliable and also makes your code ugly.

Try this:

```
my_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(),"What\'s happening")]')
```

or:

```
my_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS, '//div[data-testid="tweetTextarea_0"]')
```

Using XPath is a bad practice because if the element will be moved to another div or span - your XPath will be broken. Always prefer working with:

1. CSS and ID
2. CSS and Class
3. CSS and attibutes
4. XPATH with text contains
5. XPATH with match text (full match)
6. If no other way possible - use only XPath

Comment: XPath is just a syntax, a way to locate a node, similarly to CSS Selector.  XPath is even more powerful tool than CSS Selector. Relative XPath like `//div[@class='className']` is reliable absolutely as `div.className` CSS Selector

Comment: @Prophet Yes, you can use Xpath with attributes. Yet Xpath syntax is longer and more error prone. That's why I'm always start with CSS expression and if it not possible I'm using Xpath

Comment: It's not longer and not more error prone. Maybe you just not familiar enough with XPath, it's OK, just don't claim what you don't know.

Comment: @Prophet Xpath starts with // and before every attribute you need to use @. This is confusing and a lot of testers forget these symbols. That is why (at least by my opinion) Xpath is error prone.

Comment: In python you have to keep the indentation while many junior programmers have problems with that. So, Python is a very error prone language and we never should use it!

Comment: @Prophet I never said that we should never use Xpath. I just said to prefer CSS over Xpath...

Comment: OK, you should always prefer Java on Python because of indentation. But stop, in java you will have to put `;` after each step. Trouble... So, it's better to use recording tools. Yeah, לך על זה :)

Comment: @Prophet תהיה נחמד, אני מנסה לעזור פה לכולם. לא בא לריב ולא בא להתקיל משתמשים

Comment: אני מבין אותך. רק שנראה לי שאתה פשוט לא מכיר טוב את הנושא וזה בסדר כפי שכתבתי לך כבר. וזה בסדר. עם זאת XPATH הוא דרך מצויינת ל לעבוד איתו, כלי עם הרבה יותר אפשרויות מאשר CSS_SELECTOR . ואני גם לא בא לריב, רק להעיר

Answer (score 0):

Using the XPath, you can find an element in different ways. It looks like you have copied the XPath generated by your browser. But it's a bit massive.
HTML elements usually have unique parameters such as class, id, name, etc. So you need to find one to write a short relative XPath.

For example, this element is the only one on the page that has a class "notranslate public-DraftEditor-content." So, the XPath could be:

```
Xpath=//div[@class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content"]
```

Comment: I suppose the `notranslate ` is browser/client dependant. I don't see it in inspect-tool

Comment: You may be right. I have checked only using the latest PC versions of Chrome and Firefox, and they both display that parameter. It looks like an author's browser has it too. You can see it in the first screenshot.